# How do I make a div-element move to a random position and also get random color when it is clicked using Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

This is the task that I am stuck with:

**Exercise 4**

*Here are some examples of colors as they are used in CSS:
Red: hsl (0, 100%, 50%)
Green: hsl (100, 100%, 50%)
Blue: hsl (250, 100%, 50%)
Note that only the first number changes between these tones.
You should use this to create round  elements with random background colors. In addition, use what you have learned about positioning to place the elements in random positions when you click on the circle.*

This is my code so far for the task:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        body{
            height:100%;
        }

        div {
            
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            }

    </style>
    <script>
        let bodyEl=document.querySelector("body");
        let divEl=document.createElement("div");
        divEl.style.backgroundColor=hsl(Math.random()*6);
        bodyEl.appendChild(divEl);
        

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl()) is always useful. It's notable, that the value of `backgroundColor` is a string, that's maybe not obvious when reading the linked MDN article.

Comment: Also read If you are providing color in `hsl` what should you pass into hsl? [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl())

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `backgroundColor` needs a `string` value. You are passing value of type number

```
divEl.style.backgroundColor=hsl(Math.random()*6);
```

If you have opened the `console`, then you would have gotten the error as:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hsl is not defined
```

So you can use:

```
const hslValue = `hsl(
  ${getRandomValue(365)},
  ${getRandomValue(100)}%,
  ${getRandomValue(100)}%
)`

divEl.style.backgroundColor = hslValue;
```

```js
let bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
let divEl = document.createElement("div");

const getRandomValue = upto => Math.floor(Math.random() * (upto + 1));

const hslValue = `hsl(
  ${getRandomValue(365)},
  ${getRandomValue(100)}%,
  ${getRandomValue(100)}%
)`
divEl.style.backgroundColor = hslValue;
bodyEl.appendChild(divEl);
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click to see the circle in action, enjoy :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    div {
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    let bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
    let divEl = document.createElement("div");
    divEl.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${(Math.random() * 100)}, 100%, 50%)`;
    bodyEl.appendChild(divEl);

    divEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${(Math.random() * 100)}, 100%, 50%)`;
        this.style.top = `${parseInt(Math.random() * 100)}px`
        this.style.left = `${parseInt(Math.random() * 100)}px`
    })

    console.log(`hsl(${(Math.random() * 100)}, 100%, 50%)`);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```